# Why is the variable not set in the gitlab ci

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to run a node script in a custom docker image based on alpine linux with node installed.

`Info` is the script that contains my node script that i want to run, so I add it to the Dockerfile.

`ADD info /apps`

But when i try to run the node script in the `gitlab-ci` file as part of CI, the command runs but the variable is empty! and I can't figure out why and where the output of the command goes.

This is part of the gitlab-ci file.

```
  image:margach/doctl-alpine-node # image contains node and the info script i want to run
  ...
  script:
    - instance=$(node /apps/info) # Instance is not set and that is what i don't know why?
```

The goal is use the variable someway under the script tag to set another variable.

```
INSTANCE = $instance
```

The script section

```
Deploy:
  image: margach/doctl-alpine-node
  stage: deploy
  script:
     - instance=$(node /apps/info)   
     -|
      cat > env.build << EOF
      BUILD_ID: 1
      INSTANCE = $instance
      EOF
```

Comment: What leads you to believe the variable is not set? Can you provide more of your `script:` and the actual error or output of the job?

Comment: This is a known issue with gitlab, apparently, gitlab does not allow command substitution in the gitlab-ci.yaml https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1325

Comment: Still, I don't think it's clear from your question where you expect to be able to use the `instance` variable. If you can provide your actual yaml, I might be able to help you with a solution or workaround

Comment: @sytech I have edited the question to provide more context but the goal is to use the variable to set another variable under the script tag

Comment: There is definitely some other issue you're having here... what you want to do should work. Please just provide your entire script section.

Comment: @sytech Add the script section

Comment: If you add `cat env.build` as an additional step after that, what is the output?

Comment: Just this ```INSTANCE=```

Comment: What you have should work. I'm not able to reproduce your problem. If I use an alpine python image and put exactly what you have, but change it to `instance=$(python -c "print('hello')")` it works fine. So, I can only imagine it's something wrong with the logic of your script or a typo. Can't really imagine anything else being the issue, unless you're using a shell other than `bash`/`sh`.

Comment: @sytech Thank you for the tips, The bug was hidden dip in the image file system.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was deep in the docker image it's self and was not related to the gitlab-ci file.

Command substitution works as expected in the gitlab-ci file so the above Deploy job works just fine.